# .Net 1.0: Is there a Serializable attribute for the Compact Framework

Tags: .net, serialization, compact-framework

Going "old school" with a .Net 1.1 Compact Framework app and I'd like to be able to serialize a list of objects to memory -- are there any serialization libraries included in the 1.0 framework?

I should add that the System.Runtime.Serialization namespace doesn't exist in the 1.1 Framework (or so my compiler says).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CF didn't support any serialization in 1.0. XML serialization was introduced in 2.0.  For binary serilization, you can use something like [proto-buf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

As an aside, I'd ask why exactly you're targeting CF 1.0 in the first place.  No device ships with it in ROM, so you're likely shipping the CF too, and in that case 2.0 and 3.5 perform far better than 1.0 in general.

Comment: The reason... It's an old app and 99% of the app works as-is but I need to add a little functionality that would be remarkably easy with serialization.  I then had the "oh sh*t" moment when I realized I have to unlearn a few things to get back to CF 1.0.